# Regexp by Unicode General Category

Tags: regular-expressions, unicode

I'm trying to implement a tokenizer for Haskell, it has a bit involved token structure that can be seen in code here:

https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/compiler/basicTypes/Lexeme.hs

In regexp-like terms it would be:

`(LowercaseLetter|OtherLetter|_)(UppercaseLetter|LowercaseLetter|OtherLetter|TitlecaseLetter|DecimalNumber|OtherNumber|'|_)*ModifierLetter*#*`

In human terms: a non-uppercase letter or underscore, followed by any numbers of letters, numbers, underscores, apostrophes followed by any number of modifier letters followed by any number of hashes.

How do I write a regexp in emacs lisp that uses Unicode General Categories as indicated above?

Comment: Seems like limited support for some Unicode general categories in regexps was added in Emacs 25 recently: https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=19878
Though it seems it's not possible to write an Emacs Lisp regexp matching all of the above categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While a regexp based solution seems to be out of the question, you could write your own little matcher, using `(get-char-code-property char 'general-category)` and comparing it's result to the various `Lx` and `Nx` categories.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.